# Wo liegt der Unterschied bei (sich) in Gefahr bringen/geraten/begeben

Tags: english-to-german, meaning-in-context, phrase

In Gefahr bringen / in Gefahr geraten / sich in Gefahr begeben

Comment: Was sagt Dein Wörterbuch dazu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich finde die Frage gut, weil sie Anlaß gibt, über die Rolle von [Funktionsverbgefügen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funktionsverbgef%C3%BCge) nachzudenken.

> 1. Der Chef brachte die Mitarbeiter in Gefahr.
> 2. Die Mitarbeiter begaben sich in Gefahr.
> 3. Die Mitarbeiter gerieten in Gefahr.

Es ist klar, daß es in allen drei Fällen um eine Gefährdung der Mitarbeiter geht. Das ist der Bedeutungsbeitrag der Präpositionalphrase *in Gefahr*.

Das Verb differenziert nach [Aktionsart](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktionsart). *Bringen* ist kausativ: Es ist das Handeln des Chefs, daß für Gefahr für die Mitarbeiter sorgt. *Sich begeben* mit obligatorisch reflexivem Objekt besagt, daß die Mitarbeiter sich durch ihr Handeln selber gefährden und daß die Gefährdung irgendwie erwartbar ist. Bei *geraten* dagegen ist die Gefährdung nicht erwartbar oder passiert unabsichtlich.

Der Grund, warum die Frage vielen als redundant erscheint, ist wahrscheinlich, daß in diesem Fall die Bedeutung gut aus der Grundbedeutung der Verben ableitbar ist. In den folgenden Beispielen habe ich den metaphorischen Ort der Gefahr durch *irgendwohin* ersetzt:

> 1. jemanden irgendwohin bringen = jemanden irgendwohin transportieren
> 2. sich irgendwohin begeben = irgendwohin gehen
> 3. irgendwohin geraten = unabsichtlich irgendwohin kommen